# Show by using the definition of a derivative that $x\sin(1/x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus

So I'm supposed to show that $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ is not differntiable at $x=0$ u\sing the definition of a derivative.

So what I've got so far is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)\sin(\frac{1}{x+h})-x\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{h}\\
=&\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)\sin((x+h)^{-1})-x\sin(x^{-1})}{h}\\
=&\lim_{h\to  0}\frac{(x+h)(\sin(x^{-1})\cos(h^{-1})+\sin(h^{-1})\cos(x^{-1}))-
x\sin(x^{-1})}{h}\\
=&\lim_{h\to  0}\frac{(x+h)(\sin(x^{-1})\cos(h^{-1})-x\sin(x^{-1}) }{h}+\frac{(x+h)\sin(h^{-1})\cos(x^{-1})}{h}\\
=&\lim_{h\to  0}  \sin(x^{-1})\frac{(x+h)\cos(h^{-1})-x}{h}+\frac{(x+h)\sin(h^{-1})\cos(x^{-1})}{h}\end{aligned}$$

I have no idea if what I have done up to this point is correct so any hints and help that can get me any further would be appreciated.

Got the right result from your answered, thanks.

Comment: Since you are only interested in the case where $x=0,$ it would simplify things a lot if you replaced each appearance of $x$ with $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the extension at $0$ by continuity of $x\sin(1/x)$. Then $f(0)=0$ and, by definition,  $f$ has a derivative at $0$ if and only if there exists the limit of $$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\sin(1/h)$$
as $h\to 0$ and it is finite. What do we conclude?

Comment: I think I understand it now thank you. I was overthinking this way too much.